# Ghostscript true black and white conversion

Tags: ghostscript

I'm trying to convert a colour pdf to a pure black and white tiff i.e. if the colour is anything other than white I want it to be pure black. At the moment I have colour lines turning speckled and faint which I believe is due to half-toning. Is there a way I can overwrite this half-toning? Examples below.

Current Output:

[image: Current output]

Desired Output:

[image: Desired Output]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shades of gray are halftoned, if you want to avoid that you need to decide on a threshold below which gray values are white, and above which gray values are black.

Then you set a transfer function that maps the values. Note that its possible for both PDF and PostScritp files to include their own transfer functions (though its rare) and these may override your own.